# Get Querystring values from Location Header in PHP

Tags: php, query-string

**UPDATE**

Let's say, my users went to this page:

```
https://www.abc.com/mypage.php
```

The response headers for that page are:

```
    Content-Length  28
    Date    XXXX
    Location    https://abc.com/error.php?target=https%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fmypage.php&
errorReason=Go+To+this+Url
    Server  MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.5 (jokes are better explained)
```

That means the page is redirecting to `https://www.abc.com/errorpage.php` with the querystring params in the `Location` header.

Now on errorpage.php, instead of using $_GET to get the querystring parameters, I wanted to get the Location header, parse out the parameters and print them.

The downside to doing $_GET is, my users can enter any crap in the querystring and my errorpage.php will print it. So i wanted to avoid that by detecting the Location header.

Is there any way to get the Location header from the redirect? I am not seeing using getallheaders() or any other PHP function.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you might want to elaborate a bit on usage context, instead of only vaguely alluding to the Location header. (Except if the first three guessed answers were useful of course). Curl request? Within the target page? (Hint: then it becomes a GET parameter). What have you tried? What's the actual purpose of pageredirect.php?

Comment: changed the description my issue. Please revire.

Comment: Does your Apache version support `apache_request_headers()`?

Comment: The `Location:` header is sent to the HTTP client. *Outgoing direction*. The browser then requests the mentioned page. In that *incoming HTTP request*, there will be no Location header. You cannot access it.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out if the browser request was a redirect or a regular request?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for something other than a simple `$_GET`?

```
$target = $_GET['target'];

$errorReason = $_GET['errorReason'];
```

Comment: I am looking for getting the "location" header and not just plain $_GET.. I believe that the location header is only available on a redirect

Answer (score 1):

if you are executing the script:

`$target = $_GET['target'];
$errorReason = $_GET['errorReason'];`

if all you have is the URL:

```
$url = "https://abc.com/pageredirect.php?target=https%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fredirecttopage.php&errorReason=Simple+redirect";
$urlObj = parse_url($url);
$getVars = $urlObj['query'];
parse_str($getVars);
echo "Target: ".$target." and errorReason: ".$errorReason;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get those URL parameters using the `$_GET` array:

```
$_GET['target'];

$_GET['errorReason'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are in the `$_GET` variable

```
$_GET['target'];

$_GET['errorReason'];
```

Comment: How do I get the entire location header?